# Creating a three column layout with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a three column layout with PHP/HTML/CSS. The left column contains an image then text underneath that image, each image and text is on a separate line. The right column is the same as the left column, but with different images and texts. The middle column contains images and texts NEXT to each other, so one image and one text is on one line, one image and one text is on the next line and so forth. I have a container div that will house these columns, the container is 85% of the page. So each column will be roughly 28%. Right now, I am focusing on just the left and right columns. These columns only have images and not text for simplicity sake (My output image). When I run the code, the output is each image sitting next to each other, instead of each image being on a separate line floating to their respective positions.

PHP/HTML

```
 <?php
        $resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

        if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0)
        {
           while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
           {
            $id = $rows["id"];
            $images = $rows["image"];
            $text = $rows["text"];

            echo "<div id=container>";
            if ($id > 3 && $id < 8)
            {
                echo "<div id=left>";
                echo "<img src=$images>";
                echo "<p>$text</p>";
                echo "</div>";  
            }

            if ($id > 8)
            {
                echo "<div id=right>";
                echo "<img src=$images>";
                echo "<p>$text</p>";
                echo "</div>";  
            }
            echo "</div>";  
           }
        }
 ?>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
    height: auto;
}

#left{
    float: left;
    width: 28.33%;  
}

#left img{
    width: 100%;
}

#right{
    float: right;
    width: 28.33%;
}

#right img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is how the output looks like:
[image]

Dataset:

```
<div id=container></div><div id=container></div><div id=container></div><div id=container><div id=left><img src=http://www.clker.com/cliparts/R/r/2/q/P/4/blue-number-one-hi.png><br><p>4</p></div></div><div id=container><div id=left><img src=http://bsccongress.com/im3/blue-number-two-clip-art.png><br><p>5</p></div></div><div id=container><div id=left><img src=http://www.clker.com/cliparts/L/H/T/b/g/N/three-md.png><br><p>6</p></div></div><div id=container><div id=left><img src=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-x0uSxqUaYQA/UCEr1WV_1AI/AAAAAAAAC_0/QHrtbsfcK1s/s1600/blue-number-four-md.png><br><p>7</p></div></div><div id=container></div><div id=container><div id=right><img src=http://bsccongress.com/im7/blue-number-five-clip-art.png><p>9</p></div></div><div id=container><div id=right><img src=http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Rid/gq7/Ridgq7AnT.png><p>10</p></div></div>
```

It is creating an inline of the images instead of putting them on separate lines. How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that your PHP script is generating? Also can you add $id into the <p> tag so we can see the id from the database since the CSS is dependent on that?

Comment: add a line break (?)

Comment: @JosephEvans I just added that dataset in the question

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried adding a line break, but it doesn't affect anything, the outcome still turns out the same. Is there any way of doing it rather than my way?

Comment: An ID is only supposed to be used once. You should use classes for repeated elements.

Comment: @rybo111 The left and right divs are unique though?

Comment: I was referring to `id=container` but `left` and `right` are common class names too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Grid layout

Since you are looking for a grid layout, you would find a framework such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) very helpful. With Bootstrap, your HTML would be as simple as:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">Left</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Middle</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Right</div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use a library for some reason (why not?) then take a look at their CSS.

## Don't repeat yourself

Create your class as a variable, then create the HTML:

```
$class = 'middle';
if( something_here ){
  $class = 'left';
}
echo "<div class='$class'>Content</div>";
```

## Convert special characters

Your database variables might contain characters that cause errors in your HTML. To prevent that, create a simple function:

```
function html($str){
  return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Then use:

```
<?php echo html($row['field_name']); ?>
```

## Your images issue

If you want your images to be blocks, simply use a class called `block` on your images, and create this CSS:

```
.block{
  display:block;
}
```

## PHP templating

Instead of:

```
$this = $row['this'];
$that = $row['that'];
echo "<p>$this</p>";
echo "<div>$that</div>";
```

You can actually jump between PHP and HTML:

```
<?php if( something_here ){ ?>
<p><?=html($row['this'])?></p>
<div><?=html($row['that'])?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now your code is shorter, easier to edit, and easier to read, including your source code.